# gfortran loss of precision in mixed integer and real calculations

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm working on porting some old Fortran code that used to run on an IBM AIX 4.3 machine (IBM XL Fortran).  I've run in to the following calculation in the legacy code that produces the wrong answer when compiled with gfortran on an x86_64 machine running CentOS 7.7.

```
ISCRATCH2 = ISCRATCH2 + (7 * (2.**16)) + TEMP2
```

The initial value of ISCRATCH2 is X'0B000000' and the value of TEMP2 is 4053.  The result of the calculation is X'B070FD0' and it should be X'B070FD5'.  If I remove the dot from the 2 (making it an integer instead of a real) the value is correct.  Here's a small program that demonstrates the problem.

```
      program main
      implicit none

      Integer*2 TEMP1
      Integer*2 TEMP2
      Integer*4 ISCRATCH1
      Integer*4 ISCRATCH2
      Integer*4 ISCRATCH3

      ISCRATCH1 = X'0B000000'
      ISCRATCH2 = X'0B000000'
      TEMP1 = 4053
      TEMP2 = 4053

      ISCRATCH3 = 7 * (2.**16)
      ISCRATCH3 = X'0B000000' + ISCRATCH3 + TEMP2

      ISCRATCH1 = ISCRATCH1 + (7 * (2**16)) + TEMP1

      ISCRATCH2 = ISCRATCH2 + (7 * (2.**16)) + TEMP2

      Print 1102, ISCRATCH1, TEMP1
1102  FORMAT('ISCRATCH1 is ', Z8, ' and TEMP1 is ', Z8)

      Print 1103, ISCRATCH2, TEMP2
1103  FORMAT('ISCRATCH2 is ', Z8, ' and TEMP2 is ', Z8)

      Print 1104, ISCRATCH3, TEMP2
1104  FORMAT('ISCRATCH3 is ', Z8, ' and TEMP2 is ', Z8)

  end program main
```

When I run the above program it gives the following output

```
ISCRATCH1 is  B070FD5 and TEMP1 is      FD5
ISCRATCH2 is  B070FD0 and TEMP2 is      FD5
ISCRATCH3 is  B070FD5 and TEMP2 is      FD5
```

If I add

```
-ffpe-trap=inexact
```

to the compiler options, I get a floating point exception on line 20.

Is this expected behavior?  If so, why does it get the correct answer and not raise a floating point exception if I split it in to multiple lines (ISCRATCH3 calculations)?  I'm using gfortran 4.8.5-39 on CentOS 7.7.  It seems this code works correctly with the IBM compiler.  I realize that it's a little silly to mix data types in this way and it could be fixed by just changing the code.  However, this kind of thing is used in lots of places throughout the code of a very large program.  Is there anything I can do to fix this problem without having to find each of these instances?

Comment: The code is clearly non-conforming Fortran, so a compiler can give you any answer.  Hexidecimal literal constants start with `Z`.  Hexidecimal cannot appear in an expression (i.e, lines 10, 11, and 16 are invalid).

Comment: The answers to your questions are: yes; a real is converted to a integer on assignment then added to other integers in a later expression; and, no.  The reason is simple.  A 32-bit signed integer has 31-bits of precision.  Assuming a 32-bit IEEE-754 floating point entity, the expressions with `2.**16` have 24-bits of precision.

Comment: It would worth checking how much `2.0**16` in itself is [as a floating point number]. The compiler/rtl might use formula `exp(16*ln(2.0))` which might give non-exact answer.

Comment: @Lorinczy, a Fortran compiler might convert `2.**16` to `exp(16*ln(2.))`, but it is not a very good compiler.  With gfortran, the expression is constant-folded by 4 multiplications.

Answer (score -1):

After some more experimentation the problem seems to be (aside from the fact that the code is poorly formatted) with the the addition of 0x0B000000 and that number being outside the precision of a 32 bit float as suggested by @steve.  I think what's going on in the original statement is that because one of the values is a real it converts them all to reals before converting the answer back to an integer during the assignment.

To further demonstrate the problem executing `ISCRATCH4 = 184549376 + 10.` results in 184549392 where `ISCRATCH4 = 184549376 + 10` results in 184549386.  Interestingly `ISCRATCH4 = 184549376 + 1.` just returns 184549376.  If ISCRATCH4 is changed from and Integer*4 to Real*4, all expressions return the correct answer.

I found that if I add `-fdefault-real-8` to the compile options the answer is always correct and the floating point exception goes away.  I assume this because the conversion to real of the 0x0B000000 (or 184549376) constant is now big enough to hold the number without loosing precision.  This fix should work for my application.  Is there any reason this is undesirable other than the increase in memory usage?

Comment: The rules of mixed-mode arithmetic are well-specified in the Fortran standard.  `2.**16` is default real kind.  The integers in the RHS are promoted to default real kind during expression evaluation.  Then, the default real kind value is converted to `INTEGER*4` (yes, I know this declaration is nonstandard) upon assignment.

Comment: Using `-fdefault-real-8` is a bad, bad, idea.  If you're going to fix the problem, then do it correctly.  Gfortran developers ought to remove`-fdefault-real-8`.  It is broken and should be avoided.  The correct way to fix your computation is to use the intrinsic functions`INT` and/or `REAL` to do the conversions.  Try `ISCRATCH2 = ISCRATCH2 + INT(7 * (2.**16), KIND(1)) + TEMP2`.  This works because `2.**16` is an exactly representable integral floating point value, and INT() converts it to default integer kind so the RHS expression is evaluated as integer instead of real.

Comment: @evets, thanks for your response. Can you provide more details about why `-fdefault-real-8` is a bad idea and what other problems I might expect from using it? I realize that changing the code is the correct way to do it and that's not a problem for that one line. The problem is that my team and I are porting a very large application that has over 200,000 lines Fortran code. My concern is that there may be many other instances of this in the code that won't be easy to identify without evaluating every line of code. Is there a better way to identify where in the code this behavior is happening?

Comment: -default-real-8 breaks storage association.  If this is old code, it likely contains `COMMON` and `EQUIVALENCE`.  storage association is rather important with these features.  Note, if you are linking to external libraries you may need to compile those libraries with -fdefault-real-8 option.  During the port, you might consider using -freal-4-real-8 and similar options, but even these should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @evets, thanks for the extra detail.  The code does indeed use `COMMON` blocks and `EQUIVALENCE` statements. I'll consult with my team and we'll figure out the best way forward.  Thanks again!